# Making an URL out of modified database fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a button that when the user clicks it, it must go to a specified URL.

But I have to create my URL out of the values coming from database and most importantly, I need to modify the values coming from database before I make a URL out of it.

Suppose the values from database is

```
country- France
hotel - Hotel Movenpick
```

Now first I have to turn the capitals from above values to lowercase, then spaces to '-' sign.

Then i will have to create my URL with these modified values as below.

```
http://www.travel.com/france/hotel-movenpick
```

I have never done this before. Please provide me some reference for doing this task. I am coding in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
string fixedCountry = country.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                             .Replace(" ", "-");
string fixedHotel = hotel.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    .Replace(" ", "-");

string url = "http://www.travel.com/" + fixedCountry + "/" + fixedHotel;
```

Note that this *won't* fix up any accented characters or other symbols. It becomes more complicated if you want to do that. It will depend on how much you trust your data to not contain that sort of thing.

If you need to make this any more complicated, or need to do it anywhere else, I suggest you create a "string fixing" method which munges it appropriately, then call it for each of your fields.

EDIT: Removing accented characters is interesting. .NET makes this fairly easy, but I don't know what it will do for your "ae" situation - you may need to special-case that. Try this though, as a starting point:

```
static string RemoveAccents (string input) 
{ 
    string normalized = input.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD); 
    Encoding removal = Encoding.GetEncoding 
        (Encoding.ASCII.CodePage, 
         new EncoderReplacementFallback(""), 
         new DecoderReplacementFallback("")); 
    byte[] bytes = removal.GetBytes(normalized); 
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes); 
}
```

Comment: I'd argue you need a couple of calls to  Uri.EscapeDataString in there, to protect from invalid characters url in the country or hotel names.

Comment: i need to even convert some special language specified characters as well for example  ä to ae . Do u think i can do them as above

Comment: @David: That's what I meant about trusting the data. I suspect it's more of a case of "if there are non-urlsafe characters, I want to throw an exception rather than continue with an escaped form." It depends on the use case though.